# the categories tabel having foreign key, when i am adding new categories it does not generating the admin id from admin tabel

Tags: php

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecommerce`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`adminId`) REFERENCES `admin` (`aid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`cName`, `cDp`, `cDate`, `adminId`) VALUES ('samsung', 'm124.jpg', '2019-Sep-Tue 04:09:24', 'FALSE')
```

Filename: `C:/xampp/htdocs/ecommerce/system/database/DB_driver.php`

Line Number: 691
**this is the error..**

Code of customhelper.php file

```
    function getAdminId()
    {
        $C=get_instance();
        if ($C->session->userdata('aid')) {
            $res=$C->session->userdata('aid');
            return '$res';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'FALSE';
        }

    }
```

This function is jumping to else loop and returning false.

Comment: What is unclear? You can not insert a new record into `categories` with a value for the `adminId` column, that is not actually in the `admin.aid` column …

Comment: You're trying to insert a "FALSE" string into the `adminId` column in the `categories` table, which doesn't seem to exist in the `admin` table's `aid` column

Comment: `return '$res';` returns a string containing the literal _text_ `$res` btw. … someone should go and have a good read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php first of all, apparently.

Comment: _“this function is jumping to else loop and returning false..”_ - so is that the actual question here, why that happens? Well we are hardly in a position to tell you - you didn’t give us nearly enough information. So far we don’t know even if you have written this yourself, or if it is part of some sort of established shop system/framework, … All we can tell you is that this apparently doesn’t find the admin ID set in the session, as it expects to.